# Replacement of non-ascii character in R function without warning in devtools::check()

Tags: r

I've written a function, which extracts coordinate numbers from strings. E.g. "E 10,9598 °" will be 10.9598.

```
extract_coordinates <- function(x) {
  coord <- gsub(x = x, pattern = "[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]", 
    replacement = "")
  coord <- gsub(x = coord, pattern = "°", replacement = "")
  coord <- gsub(x = coord, pattern = "[:space:]", replacement = "")
  coord <- gsub(x = coord, pattern = ",", replacement = ".")
  as.numeric(coord)
}
```

When I run devtools::check() though this will give me a warning because "°" is a non-ascii character. I tried using the unicode "U+00B0" as a pattern in gsub but that doesn't work.

How do I have to change my code, so there is no warning anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `charToRaw("°")` to get the `\uxxxx` escape code, and then use that in the R code. For example, I have code that uses `ã` in the word `Não`. To get through `devtools::check()`, this is needed:

```
 charToRaw("ã")  # answer is \u00a3
```

Then, `Não` becomes `N\u00a3o` in my code, and problem solved.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your answer, but I tried: `x = "E 10,9598 °"` and then `gsub(x = x, pattern = "b0", replacement = "")` and this returns `NA` on a Windows machine. `b0` is the unicode for `°`.

Comment: @needRhelp, you need the actual `\u00` part as well. Try `gsub(x = x, pattern = "\u00b0", replacement = "")`, that should work.